# Is there any way to block ads in windows edge?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-edge

Just installed win 10 and everything works great, but is there any way to block ads in edge browser? installed ad block in windows but no use so are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

There's a few alternative ways to block spam other than extensions.

One would be to do it at a DNS level - either the ugly, brute force, but local way, using a hosts file (There's many of these floating around on the internet.) There's some reports an excessively large hosts file has an adverse effect on performance, but its probably the 'simplest' way. Google would help you find a [few options](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=hosts%20file%20adblocking) - the [mvp](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm) and [someonewhocares](http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/) lists are the big ones I know of. Pick *one* and add stuff, since there's lots of overlap

Alternately you can use dns based blocking - [opendns](https://www.opendns.com/) has ad blocking as far as I know.

Don't forget to flush your dns cache once this is done.

You can also run a local proxy for adblock - [privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) is the one that comes to mind, and convert your existing adblock filters to it. You can probably run one copy for your entire network. There's probably other options here so you might want to look around.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use the reading mode in Edge (click the reader icon in toolbar).

It's not a perfect solution but might work against most of the adds.

> This re-formats whatever pages you’re looking at into an easy-to-read
>   layout that’s free of adverts, menus and other distractions.

More [here](http://www.trustedreviews.com/project-spartan-review).

How it will look like by comparison of before and after:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to block sites at DNS level by editing your `hosts` file:

1. Download the hosts list file from [Blocking Unwanted Connections with a Hosts File](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm) or more specifically there is a batch file that will install it for you from this [specific link from that page](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.zip)
   Download it, extract it and run mvps.bat as administrator, or simply copy the `hosts` file to the correct location yourself.
   *(This is a precompiled list of known ad-sites that is set to 0.0.0.0 in hosts file so as to block those.)*
2. Open regedit and go to the following path
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DnsCache\Parameters`
   and create a `DWORD(32-bit) Value` and name it as `MaxCacheTtl` as set it to `1`
   *(`MaxCacheTtl` as the name indicates Maximum-Cache-Time-to-live determines how long the Domain Name System (DNS) server can save a record of a recursive name query)*
3. Restart your computer to apply changes.

Answer (score 0):

i've recently seen a post that you can manually add a hosts list for blocking, but i haven't tried it yet, because i didnt' recognize the link they provided to a host list file.  it makes sense, based on how my android phone blocks ads.

i'm thinking about getting a host list from one of the other servers that i do trust, such as one of those i use for either android or chrome, and just pushing that to the appropriate location.

Answer (score 0):

Edge now supports extensions including adblockers e.g. there is port of uBlock Origin (Beta) https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/ublock-origin/9nblggh444l4